# Maximal dimension of a vector space of square matrices in which every nonzero matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, contest-math, determinant

> I'm interested in the maximal dimension of a subspace $V\leq\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ in which every nonzero matrix is invertible.

**Odd $n$:** For odd $n$ the maximum is $1$: if $A$ and $B$ would be linearly independent, then $\det(xA+B)$ is an odd polynomial of degree $\leq n$ with leading coefficient $\det A\neq0$, so it has a real root $x$; hence $0\neq xA+B$ is not invertible.

**Even $n$:** For $n$ even the maximum can be no larger than $n$: if $A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}$ would be linearly independent, then the first row of every nontrivial linear combination must be nonzero, meaning that the first rows of $A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}$ are linearly independent, contradicting $\dim\mathbb R^n=n$.

For $n=2$ the maximum is $2$, as $\begin{vmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{vmatrix}=a^2+b^2\neq0$ for $a,b$ not both zero.

For $n=4$ the maximum is $4$, as
$$\begin{vmatrix}-a&b&c&d\\ b&a&-d&c\\ c&d&a&-b\\ d&-c&b&a\end{vmatrix}=-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.$$

> **Questions:** For $n$ even, is the maximal dimension always $n$? Do similar such matrices exist with determinant $\pm\,(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)^{n/2}$?

*This is an attempt to generalize problem $3$ of the [PUMA 2016](http://prime.ugent.be/sites/default/files/2015-2016/puma/vragen.pdf).*

Comment: I think your last question may be equivalent to the existence of Hadamard matrices, which is in general an unsolved problem (but I think they only exist for $n=2$ and multiples of 4, so in particular not for $n=6$).

Comment: The answer to your first question is no. This is a known result, proved by Adams (1962), *Vector fields on spheres*, Annals of Mathematics, 75(3): 603-632. Put it simply, the maximal dimension of subspace of real invertible $n\times n$ matrices (except the zero matrix) is given by the Hurwitz-Radon numbers $\rho(n)$, which is defined as follows -- if $n$ is the product of $2^{4a+b}$ and some odd number, then $\rho(n)=8a+2^b$ (so, when $n$ is odd, $\rho(n)\equiv1$). The first ten Hurwitz-Radon numbers for the  **even** $n$s are 2, 4, 2, 8, 2, 4, 2, 9, 2, 4.

Comment: @user1551 You can post that as an answer, as it also implies the nonexistence of those matrices (at least, for $n\neq8$), answering my 2nd question. The Hurwitz-Radon numbers are [A003484 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003484).